# Zend Db Unit Test failed when try to truncate

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

Basically my test failed due to "Integrity Violation" when tries to TRUNCATE the tables in a bad order.

Every Db test case extends PHPUnit_DatabaseTestCase_Abstract which truncates the tables before testing. As soon as I have a row at Property all the tests failed due to Error: COMPOSITE[TRUNCATE] operation failed on query.

This is my database schema:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `project`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project` (
  `project_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`project_id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `project_id_UNIQUE` (`project_id` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `customer`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer` (
  `customer_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `firstname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `telephone` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `customer_id_UNIQUE` (`customer_id` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `property`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `property` (
  `property_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `project_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `customer_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`property_id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `property_id_UNIQUE` (`property_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_property_project` (`project_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_property_customer1` (`customer_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_property_project`
    FOREIGN KEY (`project_id` )
    REFERENCES `project` (`project_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_property_customer1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id` )
    REFERENCES `customer` (`customer_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Am I testing wrong? How could I specify to truncate in a properly order before testing?

Zend Version 1.11.5

The error is supposed to be fixed (check [framework zend forum](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-7936?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin%3aactivity-stream-issue-tab)

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use phpunit to test your database, I think it would be better to extend and use ZF's class for this: [Zend_Test_PHPUnit_DatabaseTestCase](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.test.phpunit.db.html) rather than directly extend PHPUnit_DatabaseTestCase_Abstract. Maybe this is a part of your problem.

Comment: Hi Marcin, thanks for reply.
My database test cases extends PHPUnit_DatabaseTestCase_Abstract, because this is a personal class which extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_DatabaseTestCase.